# 200 ok response to request before work is done in aws lambda

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading, http, aws-lambda, request

Im trying to make a 200 ok response to a request before the work is done, however the work i need to do takes longer than the 3 seconds i need to make the response in.

Im working in aws lambda and the way i approached this was through threading:

```
t = threading.Thread(target=worker, args=(xml,))
t.start()

# So that you can return before worker is done
return response(200)
```

However, even when I threaded the work to be done in the background, it seems that aws lambda won't finish the work. It seems that as soon as the response is made, lambda just shuts down. For example, if the work takes 2 seconds to be done, then the following will not work:

```
t = threading.Thread(target=worker, args=(xml,))
t.start()

# So that you can return before worker is done
return response(200)
```

but if we sleep for 2 seconds, the work will be done:

```
t = threading.Thread(target=worker, args=(xml,))
t.start()
time.sleep(2)
# So that you can return before worker is done
return response(200)
```

If so, what can I do to make a 200 ok response to the request with aws lambda, but also have the work be done in the same lambda function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A threading solution won't work, because once you send a response your Lambda environment will be shutdown. You need to trigger an AWS Lambda function in `async` mode instead of `event`. See [this guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/set-up-lambda-integration-async.html) for one possible solution.

Alternatively you could have your current Lambda function simply call another Lambda function with an `async` event type that does all the actual work, and then return the `200` response code.

Comment: Is it possible to use the requests module to send an OK response to the response url and then continue with the work?

Comment: What response URL? There is no "response URL" in the sense that you are talking about. The browser has an open TCP connection waiting for a response. There isn't a URL for that, it's an established connection between the browser and API Gateway.

Comment: @MarkB I cannot see my comment, I would like to know who deleted it, I didn't write anything that could justify a deletion. Anyway it was a comment to tom in your support, because he's quite clearly speaking about slack api (I'm quite sure) but he's not helping us much if he's not giving all the detail. And I still would like to know *where* is my comment.

Comment: Now your comment disappeared. Can I have a clarification on what's going on here?

Answer (score 0):

I will assume you're using AWS API Gateway to call your lambda function (hence the 200 status code return).

There are two ways to call a lambda, the `sync` way and the `event` or `async` way. API Gateway by default uses the first way unless you explicitly tell it otherwise. In order to make your lambda integration `async` by default you should add a custom header:

```
X-Amz-Invocation-Type: Event
```

In your API Gateway console. You can also add a

```
InvocationType: Event
```

header in you client calls